# Google TXT record verification with Terraform on Digital Ocean

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, terraform

I am trying to verify I couple websites I host under an domain I own. Google tells me

> 1. Add the TXT record below to the DNS configuration for cescoferraro.xyz.
>
>    google-site-verification=RANDOM_HASH

What I am trying:

```
resource "digitalocean_domain" "domain" {
  name = "cescoferraro.xyz"
  ip_address = "${digitalocean_droplet.master.ipv4_address}"
}

resource "digitalocean_record" "googleconfirmation" {
    domain = "${digitalocean_domain.domain.name}"
    type = "TXT"
    name = "google-site-verification"
    value = "RANDOM_HASH"
}

resource "digitalocean_record" "googleconfirmationnnn" {
    domain = "${digitalocean_domain.domain.name}"
    type = "TXT"
    name = "what"
    value = "google-site-verification=RANDOM_HASH"

}
resource "digitalocean_record" "googleconfirmationnssnn" {
    domain = "${digitalocean_domain.domain.name}"
    type = "TXT"
    name = "@"
    value = "google-site-verification=RANDOM_HASH"
}
```

I have not been able to verify my domain yet, might be due to DNS cache. I know this things take a while, but whats is the right way?

Comment: Your record [looks ok now](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#TXT/cescoferraro.xyz), the resource with `name = "@"` is the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my expirience, google made a typo in the verification intructions when you are not trying to verify `www.domain.com`.
When trying to verify the domain `mycoolhostname.domain.com`, as per question, it explicitly tell you:

> 1. Add the TXT record below to the DNS configuration for domain.com.

When it should be saying

> 1. Add the TXT record below to the DNS configuration for mycoolhostname.domain.com.

So terraform code, AS @DusanBajic suggested, would be something like this:

```
resource "digitalocean_domain" "mycoolhostname" {
  name = "mycoolhostname.domain.com"
  ip_address = "${digitalocean_droplet.master.ipv4_address}"
}
resource "digitalocean_record" "google-mycoolhostname-confirmation" {
    domain = "${digitalocean_domain.mycoolhostname.name}"
    type = "TXT"
    name = "@"
    value = "google-site-verification=COOL_HASH"
}
```